# Is that an object factory?

Tags: java, factory

I have the following class:

```
public class Report{
   //contains some data fields
}
```

and

```
public class ReportFactory{

    //The fields below are in fact restrictions
    private List<Integer> idList;
    private OrderProperty property;
    private Integer amount;
    //ad so forth

    //GET, SET

    public Report getReport(){
         Report report = new Report;
         //Getting report depending on which of those fields were setted
         return report;
    }
}
```

My question is if it correct to say that `ReportFactory` is actually an object Factory. Coould it mislead the developer who try to understand the code?

Comment: Why not just "report factory"?

Comment: @MarounMaroun What do you mean?

Comment: I mean why to call it "object factory" and not just... "report factory"?

Comment: What exactly is your question? `ReportFactory` looks like something that creates reports, so yes, it's a factory class. Since reports are objects, yes, you could call it an "object factory". There's nothing really special about the words "object factory". I would call the method `createReport()` instead of `getReport()`.

Comment: Given that it depends upon mutable state of the `ReportFactory`, I'd argue it's a bit more like a `ReportBuilder`.

Comment: @Jesper I'm used to thinking about a factory as a class that is going to create instance of the subclasses of some class.

Comment: @user3663882 What is the purpose of the restrictions. How do they impact the creation of a report object?

Answer (score 2):

Due to the fact that you are producing an instance of the `Report` class using a method, it is by definition a factory pattern, yes.

Anyway, usually in factory patterns the restrictions or parameters to describe the instance you wish to produce are directly passed using method parameters and not using fields.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be fair to say that `ReportFactory.getReport()` is a factory method for creating instances of `Report` class, and developer should understand the same. However you can read more to have a better Factory pattern implementation.

Comment: What do you mean a better factory implementation?

Answer (score 0):

It is some what correct.

Actually, what exactly object factory means it should initialize object based on their type and return the corresponding object reference.

For example, if Shape is an object factory, then get() method in Shape class should initialize shapes like Rectangle, Square, Triangle etc... and return the corresponding instance based on the user requirement.

If your ReportFactory class initializes and returns the different types of report objects based on the user parameter in getReport() method, then yes your ReportFactory class is object factory.

Comment: The whole business with creating specific subclass instances is not *necessary* to call it a factory - that's just one possible way that you can implement a factory. "Factory" just means that the main responsibility of the factory is to create objects of some type, in this case `Report` objects. How exactly the factory works internally doesn't influence whether you can call it a "factory" or not.